# Pressure Drop in a Moving Bed

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, friction, flow

I am trying to find a way how to calculate a pressure drop in a moving bed filled with uniform spherical metal balls moving through an inclined pipe along with the flow.

Balls are fully packed and form a moving bed.

I know that a fixed/packed bed pressure drop can be approximated with an Ergun (1952), which is applicable for laminar and turbulent flow, however, I expect the pressure drop to be smaller for the moving bed.

I cannot find any relevant references that address this issue and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: So you have a concentrated suspension of particles flowing through a pipe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ChetMiller I have updated my question to make it more specific. Hopefully, it is clearer now.

Comment: Is there friction between the bed and the wall?

Comment: @ChetMiller There is friction between the bed and the wall as well as between the balls, however for simplicity, we can ignore those for now.

Comment: If we neglect the wall friction, there is no stopping the bed from traveling at the same speed as the fluid (no relative velocity).

Comment: @ChetMiller How would we tackle the given problem with friction (bed<->balls, ball<-> ball)?

Comment: You mentioned the Ergun Equation.  This would be the place to start.  Determine the force of the flowing fluid on the bed for a given difference in velocities.